# Wpf Grid resizing not working after splitter moved

Tags: wpf

I have the following wpf code.

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=toggleButtonShowGeneratedCode, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>

            <Button Content="Button 1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5" ResizeDirection="Columns" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>

        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=toggleButtonShowGeneratedCode, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>

            <Button Content="Button 2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Name="toggleButtonShowGeneratedCode" Width="50" Content="Toggle"/>
</Grid>
```

Toggle button is supposed to collapse and expand Button 2. When the Button 2 is collapsed Button 1 should take its space.

This works at the startup, however after splitter is moved this stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When GridSplitter is moved it forcefully changes width of previous and next column. They are no longer `*` and `Auto` as declared, but become `*` and `N` where N is some number. Therefore Column#2 doesn't collapse when its content collapses.

suggested solution: restore column#2 width to `Auto` with some code-behind (fine for view-view interaction)

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Name="ResizableGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <!--...-->
  <ToggleButton Grid.Row="1" Name="toggleButtonShowGeneratedCode" 
                Width="50" Content="Toggle" 
                Unchecked="toggleButtonShowGeneratedCode_Unchecked"/>
```

```
private void toggleButtonShowGeneratedCode_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResizableGrid.ColumnDefinitions[2].Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
}
```

note that I added Name for Grid to access it from code